# ifstream get() not filling char array

Tags: c++, iostream

I have no clue whatsoever as to what would be doing this

```
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

#define out(a) cout << #a << ": " << a << '\n'

void print(string s)
{
  cout << s << '\n';
}

 int main()
{
  ifstream readt1;
  readt1.open("test1.yaml");

  while(readt1.good())
  {
    char cc[128];
    readt1.get(cc,128);
    out(cc);
  }
readt1.close();
}
```

that code... outputs this:

```
cc: version: 0.14.1
cc:
```

with test.yaml being this

```
version: 0.14.1
name: scrumbleship
author: dirkson
description: >
  A minecraft like game that allows you
  to build your own spaceship!
```

I've tried so many ways to get this to work, and it simply doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `readt1.ignore();` after the get() it should work:

```
  while(readt1.good())
  {
    char cc[128];
    readt1.get(cc,128);
    readt1.ignore(); // <--- add this to ignore newline
    out(cc);
  }
```

This fixes the immediate problem, but using `std::getline` and `std::string` would be better C++. Something like:

```
while(std::getline(readt1, line)) {// Do stuff}
```

Comment: Ohh my god, Where the hell is this when I need it? And where did you find it out? I will accept asap (5 minute waiting)

Comment: When you do `readt1.get(cc,128);` it extracts either `127` characters or up until the newline character (i.e, `\n`), the next time you try to read something it fails because you didn't ignore the newline.

Comment: So ignore is like skipping over it but still increasing gcount?

Comment: @alexhairyman: `ignore` extracts the newline character and discards it (and yes gcount is changed).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getline()` to read line through ifstream

Comment: I want to forgo the getline, and just read in a specific number of characters via `get()`

Comment: if your file have less than 128 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Also, I  would get the first line outside of the loop, and the loop should check for an EOF to ensure you get the whole file. Doesn't good() just imply that there is a file to read?

Comment: I think your get is just reading that one line and never progressing to the others.

Comment: Knowing this, I would fall back to parsing line by line and then parsing the data from there.

Comment: I got the same sort of problem though

Comment: What happens when you use getline()?

Comment: broken if I use anything less than the length of the line